# tkraise is not functioning

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am trying to create two buttons to switch frame config by raising different Frame above an other. but the tkraise() function doesn't seems working... Please help to check if there are any mistake or concept error of using tkraise.

Thanks for helping

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

SUNKABLE_BUTTON = 'SunkableButton.TButton'

class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):

    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         
        # __init__ function for class Tk
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # initializing frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {} 
  
        top_container = tk.LabelFrame(self, width=400, height=100, text="item")
        top_container.grid(row = 0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
        mid_container_l = tk.LabelFrame(self, width=200, height=100, text="item_a")
        mid_container_l.grid(row = 1, column=0)

        mid_container_r = tk.LabelFrame(self, width=200, height=100, text="item_b")
        mid_container_r.grid(row = 1, column=1)

        but_container = tk.LabelFrame(self, width=400, height=400, text="item")
        but_container.grid(row = 2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)
        
        for F in (One,Two):
            frame = F(self)
            self.frames[F] = frame

        btn_1 = tk.Button(but_container, text="btn_1", command=lambda : self.show_frame(One))
        btn_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        btn_2 = tk.Button(but_container, text="btn_2", command=lambda : self.show_frame(Two))
        btn_2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        #self.show_frame(One)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        print(frame)
        frame.tkraise(aboveThis=None)

class One(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        but_container_in = tk.Frame(parent, width=400, height=200, bg="yellow")
        but_container_in.grid(row = 3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

class Two(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        but_container_in_l = tk.Frame(parent, width=400, height=200, bg="green")
        but_container_in_l.grid(row = 3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

        #but_container_in_r = tk.Frame(parent, width=200, height=200, bg="red")
        #but_container_in_r.grid(row = 3, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

# Driver Code
app = tkinterApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I am expecting someone can point out mine blind spot

Comment: Do you know what ` tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)` and `but_container_in = tk.Frame(parent, ...)` do? Please look some tutorials.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I think  tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) here is to inherit parent which  is the self in tkinterApp. And, but_container_in = tk.Frame(parent, ...) here is to create a frame under parent.

Comment: Why do you need 2 frames under `parent` for class `One` and 2 more under class `Two`? The approach with `tkraise` that you are trying to implement, uses a class for each frame under `parent`.

Comment: Because I have tried to use with self, but the result did not show any frames.... that's why I changed to parent.... But this is a total error....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tkraise` is working. The problem is that you're raising frames that aren't visible on the screen so there's no visual indication that it's working.

The problem is in the definition of your classes `One` and `Two`. These classes make two frames: the instance of the class itself, and then an inner frame. Both are children of `parent`, but only the inner frame is added to the window (in this case, with `grid`).

I don't understand why you're creating an inner frame inside a class that is itself a frame. At the very least, those inner frames should be children of the class rather than children of the parent.

When you make the inner frames children of `self`, and you call `grid` on the instance of the class, your code works.

```
class One(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid(row = 3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

        but_container_in = tk.Frame(self, width=400, height=200, bg="yellow")
        but_container_in.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

class Two(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid(row = 3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

        but_container_in_l = tk.Frame(self, width=400, height=200, bg="green")
        but_container_in_l.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Things to notice:

- the inner frames are now children of `self`, since the instance of those classes are themselves frames, and the instances of the classes are the ones you need to call `tkraise` on.
- I moved the call to `grid` onto `self` rather than onto the inner frame.
- I added a call to `pack` on the inner frame since that's the simplest way to get a frame to fill its parent

Comment: Thanks !! I got it.  I know where my blind spots are.